# How to multipley two mathematical expression in python to get answer as a equation

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I want to multiply (x-5) and (x-6) in python to get the answer as x^2 - 11x +30 but dunno how to do . If someone could help me with it.

I could not even think of writing a code to try. I am a newbie to python so please help me.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc//numpy-1.9.3/reference/routines.polynomials.polynomial.html or https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.package.html#module-numpy.polynomial

Comment: How to use it pls

Comment: @lastchance while it is true that there is no real question in this post and thus no real answer to give, I do not believe "read the manual" is a proper answer. SO is here to store answers to questions, and "google it" or "read the doc" is not an acceptable answer

Comment: A good book is "Learning Scientific Programming with Python" by Christian Hill. It's in the section with sciPy.

Comment: thanks alot, while i know @Jackred was rude but ok thnx

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look to the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may want to reformulate your question so you ask a proper problem to be solved, with the specific you want. Additionally, SO is not a code writing service, you have to provide example of what you would like to do/tried/doesn't work for you if possible

Comment: You could also use symPy. It depends whether you want to do symbolic manipulation or just find the polynomial coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Sympy, as @lastchance said.

For your problem, you could use something like that:

```
from sympy import expand
expand((x-5)*(x-6))
```

Output:

```
x**2 - 11*x + 30
```

To learn more sophisticate operations, please read: [Sympy Documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/simplification.html#expand)

Matlab would be a good choice for this kind of problem too, in my opinion, even better than Python.